# How to update roles in security token in Symfony 4 without re-logging in

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to update User's roles after the user confirms its phone number.

I make the update in the database:

```
$user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);
$em->persist($user);
```

That works fine and updates the users's role in the database. (Before, users have "ROLE_UNACTIVATED" group).

However, it doesn't update the user's roles in the session (security token), so the user needs to logout and then log in one more time.

So, the question is how to update User's roles in security token?

Comment: create listener db pre update, catch that specific user and refresh token

Comment: The problem is that I can’t find the docs how to refresh the token.

Comment: which symfony version ?

Comment: Symfony version I use is 4.3

Comment: check this https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/security/user_provider.html and read about refresh user...

Comment: unfortunately, I can’t find there anything about manual security token refresh. It is said that “ By default, the core AbstractToken class compares the return values of the getPassword(), getSalt() and getUsername() methods. If any of these are different, your user will be logged out.”. That’s not I need.

Comment: I'm a little confused here:  why does the security-token have to change when the roles associated with it change?

Comment: User’s token includes User’s data (including roles) from the authentication process. So, if user was authenticated while having ROLE_UNACTIVATED role, the token has that role. But when the user’s role is being updated in database, the token isn’t. So, the token has outdate information about user.

Comment: *actually* roles by default are *bound* to the session, and not just to the user. meaning it by default requires a relogin. To change that is not quite simple, because usually the role is not change by the user itself (or a script on the user's request) but by a different user (or a command). That's a starting point, I hope. However, if your roles change, so you user changes, it can lead to the user being logged out automatically (which might be exactly what you want).

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helped ;)

Uses:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
```

Contstruct:

```
public function __construct(
    protected TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
) {}
```

Method:

```
/**
 * Refresh token roles immediately
 */
private function refreshToken(UserInterface $user): void
{
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken(
        new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'main', $user->getRoles())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that it's a right way to do that, but what I did is manually re-authenticate the user

```
public function activation(Request $request, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, LoginFormAuthenticator $formAuthenticator)
{
    ...
    //re-authenticate user to update roles in security token
    $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
        $user,
        $request,
        $formAuthenticator,
        'main'
    );
}
```

and that automatically updates security token of a user without logging out.